# Proof verification: If $\frac{1}{n}a_n\to0$, then $\frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}\to0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

I don't know how to use LaTeX that well, so I'll upload the imagines of the question and the way I tried to prove it. I am unsure if my proof is correct. If it's not correct, then could you explain why it isn't and give me a hint to prove the implication statement.

> **Question.**<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYWEv.png)</sup> Show that if
> $$ \frac{1}{n}a_n \to 0, $$
> then
> $$ \frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\} \to 0.$$

*My attempt.*<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o2GR.jpg)</sup>
Want to show:

$$ \frac{1}{n}a_n \to 0 \quad\implies\quad \frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\} \to 0. $$

We have $\frac{1}{n}a_n \to 0$ iff

$$ \forall \varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+, \ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \ \quad n \geq N \implies \left|\frac{1}{n} a_n\right| < \varepsilon. \tag{*} $$

Note, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n \leq \max\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$. If $\max\{a_1,\ldots, a_N\} = a_N$, where $N$ is the one that satisfies $\text{(*)}$, then

$$ n \geq N \quad\implies\quad \left|\frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}\right| < \varepsilon. $$

However, if $\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_N\} > a_N$, then $\left|\frac{1}{N}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_N\}\right| < \varepsilon $ might not be true. So, if $\exists M \in \mathbb{N}$, $M \geq N$, $\max\{a_1, \ldots, a_M\} = a_M$, then

$$ n \geq M \quad\implies\quad \left|\frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}\right| < \varepsilon. $$

Comment: Click on the circled "?" on the top bar near the far right. Choose "Help Center". In the middle column of Help Center, under Our Model, choose "How Can I Format Mathematics Here?" for LaTex lessons.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: OP, you may close this one by accepting one of the answers if you deem it the best

Answer (score 2):

Since $a_n/n\to 0$, then $\{a_n/n\}$ is bounded. Say
$|a_n|\le Mn,$ for some $M>0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary.

Pick $N_1\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$
n\ge N_1\quad\Longrightarrow\quad \left|\frac{a_n}{n}\right|<\varepsilon,
$$
and $N_2\in\mathbb N$, such that $MN_1/N_2<\varepsilon$.

Let $n\ge N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, and suppose that $a_k=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$.

If $k \ge N_1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}=
\left|\frac{a_k}{n}\right|=\left|\frac{a_k}{k}\right|\cdot \frac{k}{n}\le 
\left|\frac{a_k}{k}\right|<\varepsilon.
$$
If $k<N_1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}=
\left|\frac{a_k}{n}\right|\le \frac{Mk}{n}\le \frac{MN_1}{N_2} <\varepsilon.
$$
Hence, indeed, if $n\ge N$, then
$$
\frac{1}{n}\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}<\varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have $a_n/n \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ i.e. $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N_1\in\mathbb{N},\forall n\geq N_1:a_n/n<\epsilon$. If $a_n$ is bounded, there is not much to show. Hence I assume $a_n$ is unbounded. Pick $N_2\geq N_1$, s.t. $$a_{N_2}=\max\{a_1,...,a_{N_2}\} \, .$$
Now, for any $n\geq N_2$ and $\max\{a_1,...,a_n\}=a_k$ with $N_2\leq k\leq n$,
$$\frac{a_k}{n} \leq \frac{a_k}{k} < \epsilon \, .$$

---

Alternatively: If $a_n$ is bounded, there is nothing to show. Otherwise you can define a non-decreasing function $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ as in the following: First we define a subset $S=\{n_1=1,n_2,n_3,...\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ by the inductive procedure
$$\text{for}\quad m=1,2,3,... \quad \text{do} \quad \min_{k\in\mathbb{N}}(k):a_{n_m+k} \geq a_{n_m} \quad \Rightarrow \quad n_{m+1}=n_m+k\in S \, .$$
We then set $f(n_m)=a_{n_m}$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f(n)=a_{n_m}$ between two subsequent points i.e. for $n\in\{n_m,n_m+1,...,n_{m+1}-1\}$. Clearly $a_n \leq f(n),\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and furthermore, since $a_n/n \rightarrow 0$, $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}:a_n/n < \epsilon, \forall n\geq N$. But then $\forall n_m\geq N$ and $n\in\{n_m,n_m+1,...,n_{m+1}-1\}$ we have $f(n)/n=a_{n_m}/n \leq a_{n_m}/n_m<\epsilon$.

Finally for some $k\in\{1,...,n\}$ and $n\geq n_m \geq N$
$$\frac{1}{n} \max\{a_1,...,a_n\} = \frac{a_k}{n} \leq \frac{f(k)}{n}\leq \frac{f(n)}{n}<\epsilon \, .$$

Answer (score 0):

The first observation you make is on the right track: if the maximum of the sequence is somehow towards the end of the sequence, then the original convergence result already secures the desired conclusion.

Some suggestions for writing your proof:

- At the beginning, you are fixing an $\epsilon > 0$ and should make this explicit.
- By definition, there exists an $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that $\frac{|a_n|}{n} < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Now $N$ (and $\epsilon$) are fixed for the rest of the argument.
- For $n \geq N$, consider $a_I = \max\{ a_1, \dots, a_N, \dots, a_n \}$ (where the index $I = I(n)$ depends on $n$). If $I \in \{ N, N+1, \dots, n \}$, then $\frac{a_I}{n} \leq \frac{a_I}{I} < \epsilon$. This is the good case.
- For the bad case, suppose that $I \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, N - 1 \}$ instead. Now the key observation is that we do not know which index this might be as $n$ varies; however, since $N$ is finite, we can simply bound $a_I$ by the known quantity $M = \max \{ a_1, a_2, a_{N-1} \}$. Thus, in this case we have $\frac{a_I}{n} \leq \frac{M}{n}$ for all $n \geq N$; for sufficiently large $n$, say $n \geq N'$, we have $\frac{M}{n} < \epsilon$ as well.
- Combine the good and bad cases, and take $n \geq \max \{ N, N' \}$ to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short proof for comparison: For $e>0$ there exists $m_e\in \Bbb N$ such that $$(1)....\quad\forall j\ge m_e\,(|a_j/j|<e)$$ and there exists $n_e\ge m_e$ such that $$(2)....\quad (1/n_e)\max \{|a_j|:j\le m_e\}<e.$$ Now for any $n\ge n_e,$

if $j\le m_e$ then $|a_j|/n\le |a_j|/n_e<e$ by $(2),$

while if $m_e<j\le n$ then $|a_j|/n\le |a_j|/j <e$ by $(1)$.

Therefore for all $n\ge n_e$ we have $$(1/n)|\max \{a_1,...,a_n\}|\le (1/n)\max \{|a_1|,...,|a_n|\}=\max \{|a_1|/n,...,|a_n|/n\}<e.$$